# Visualise in $\mathbb{R}$: inverse of open set is open $\implies f$ continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, visualization

**Theorem**: Let $(S,d_S), (T,d_T)$ be metric spaces and $f: S\to T$. Then $f$ is continuous (1) iff every open set $D\subset T$ has an open inverse image $f^{-1}(D)$ (2).

The theorem in itself is very famous, but I have never seen something like it when $S,T\subset \mathbb{R}.$ Of course (1)$\implies$(2) is easy to imagine, but what about (2)$\implies$ (1)? It is obvious for $f(x)=x$. How about for $f(x)=x^2$? So when do the arguments work in laymans terms.

Can someone give an example, where the inverse of the open set is closed, hence $f$ is not continuous?

Comment: What do you mean when $S,T \subseteq \mathbb{R}$? I suppose you endow those with the usual topology, but these are just metric spaces again.

Comment: About your last sentence: Note that open and closed are not opposites.

Comment: Consider $f: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=0$ for $x\in (-\infty,0]$ and $f(x)=2$ for $x\in(0,\infty)$. Since $f^{-1}((-1,1))=(-\infty, 0]$ is not open, $f$ is not continuous.